# How to loop through cheerio object in reverse?

Tags: javascript, cheerio

https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio

Let's save a I have a long list of elements (1000+) that I want to loop through in reverse.  What's the most efficient way to do this?  Thanks

```
$('li').each(function(i, elem) {
  fruits[i] = $(this).text();
});
```

Comment: Does the following work? `Array.from($('li')).reverse().map(el=>$(el).text())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a for loop?

```
const li = $('li');

for (let i = li.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  $(li[i]).text();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use `$('li').size() - 1 - i` as the index:

```js
const fruits = [];

$('li').each(function(i, elem) {
  fruits[$('li').size() - 1 - i] = $(this).text();
});

console.log(fruits);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li>Apple</li>
<li>Banana</li>
<li>Pear</li>
```

Comment: Don't you think fetching `$('li').size()` repeatedly in loop will make it slower?